# disable apple push notifications when application isn't running / logged out

Tags: iphone, objective-c, push, apple-push-notifications

I am using apple push notifications to send important BUY and SELL recommendations for an application used by day traders -- I am running into a little problem that I am surprised I can't find.

I want to disable push notifications when the user isn't logged in or has closed the app. I've thought of a few ways to accomplish this, but none of them seem feasible, so I am looking for a solution through the APNS service. My thoughts were:

1. Enable push on server when user logs in, disable it when user logs out. The problem with this is if the app crashes or the user force-quits the app, pushes wont be deactivated
2. Keep a session and if it dies, disable push notifications. The problem with this is they may be logged in and have their phone in sleep for hours and the app wont poll the server to  keep that session alive, but since they didn't explicitly log out, i want to still send those pushes.

Is there a way to modify the APNS payload to say, if app is not running, drop push message? That's all I want :)

I would really appreciate any help! Thanks everyone!

Comment: I can't figure out your requirement.  In (1) you want the notifications to cease if the app is killed, but in (2) you seem to be saying you still want the notifications if the phone is powered off.

Comment: If the app crashes, and they don't want the push notifications, won't they just re-launch it and exit?

Comment: Only if the phone is in sleep for a long period of time, but the app is still active, so-to-speak. The only way I want push notifications to be sent is if the app is running and logged in. They might not open the app for days, but if they logged in and the app is still running, I want to send them.

Comment: @ceejayoz one would hope, but I am dealing with people that are surprised when they don't get notifications from our desktop client and it's not even running...

Comment: Just set up the notification to pop up whether the app is running or not.  If the user doesn't want them that will prompt him to log in and turn them off.

Comment: @HotLicks that does seem to be the direction I am headed. The problem is they could literally receive 50-100 of these a day...I guess if they do get annoying, they will definitely log in and turn them off though. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 1):

Have the app "ping" the server every 5 minutes or so, and stop sending notifications if two pings are missed.

Comment: This is part of the reason I want to push notifications in the first place -- Apple provides no reliable way to loop a ping every 5 seconds when the app didEnterBackground. I think after a few minutes of being in the background or asleep, apple doesn't allow networking. If I am wrong in thinking this, it will solve a lot of my problems.